# Locations of Batman's backup Batcaves

Tags: dc, batman

I recently read somewhere that Batman has about 8 backup Batcaves, one of which is right under the Arkham Asylum. In DC's ***Batman: No man's Land***, 4 of his Batcaves are introduced namely, **The Central Batcave**, **Batcave South**, **Northwest Batcave** (*located under Arkham Asylum*) and the **East Batcave**.

[image: The image is divided into 4 quadrants. In the upper-left, captioned "Central Batcave," is a picture of Batman's computer array in a cavern. In the upper-right, captioned "Batcave South," is a picture of what might be a boiler room with bare brick walls, pipes, and utility lighting, outfitted with bunkbeds and a single burner for cooking. In the lower-right, captioned "Batcave East," is what looks like an industrial facility with a computer set among large pipes and massive electrical insulators. In the lower left, captioned "Northwest Batcave," is a basement with a large coal-fired furnace, complete with a pile of coal and wheelbarrow, where there is a plain desk with a few computers and a laptop.]

Counting the **Batcave under the Wayne Manor**, that makes a total of five. So where are the rest of the 3 backup caves located?

Answer (score 13):

## It would appear over the years he's had more than 8.

I'm unsure as to which 3 the post you read may be referring to, however throughout his years in the comics there have been numerous mentions of caves, bases and labs that Batman has visited or operated out of.

Most of this information is sourced from the wiki (and then confirmed with comic book panels) or from [this post](https://old.reddit.com/r/BatmanMegaRT/comments/859hxv/batcaveother_bases/) on reddit by user [/u/Ame-no-nobuku](https://old.reddit.com/user/Ame-no-nobuko) providing an excellent list of details on the main batcave and other bases. I will try to list only the most relevant Batcaves and "caves" mentioned.
<sub>As usual, click all images to embiggen.</sub>

## [Batcave West](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bJQu.jpg)

In *The Outsiders (1985) #19*, Batman confirms that he has a Batcave located somewhere in the LA area, which was designed by Batman and Dr. Helga Jace.

[image: Batcave West]

### Batcave West (II?)

In *Batman Incorporated (2012) #1*, it is revealed that there exists another Batcave West located [under a sex shop in San Francisco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po5Sb.jpg). (Indirect link due to less than savoury material).

### Backup Batcave

In *Batman: Bruce Wayne - Murderer?*, Batman reveals that Alfred had a "temporary base of operations" prepared.

[image: Batman gets out of the Batmobile and walks to a bunker-type door, with a thick border, beveled corners and a wheel in the middle. He turns the wheel and pulls the door open. Ducking to enter a narrow space filled with devices, he thinks "Alfred did a good job preparing this temporary base of operations. At least HE hasn't turned against me." Opening a circular hatch in the ceiling and climbing up, he thinks "He doesn't understand either, though. I suppose none of them can..."]

## [Batcave East](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF7Nn.jpg)

After its original reveal in *Batman: No Man's Land Secret Files*, the existence of Batcave East is reiterated in the 2012 *Batman Incorporated #12*.

## [Base next to Crime Alley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmVi7.jpg)

In *Batman (2011) #0* it is revealed that Batman has a base right next to Crime Alley that has sewer access, a vehicle hangar, a lab and an armoury.

## [Has mini-batcaves scattered across the city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvmFg.jpg)

In *Batman: Shadow of the Bat #88*, Batman reveals to Robin that he had numerous "caves" prepared around the city.

## [Backup Batcave north of Gotham](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZIVC.jpg)

In *All Star Batman #3* we find out that a couple hundred miles north of Gotham there is another backup Batcave located near a walnut farm.

## [Emergency Batcave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxSeL.jpg)

In *Batman (1940) #186*, Batman and Robin escape from Poison Ivy's hideout to an emergency Batcave on the outskirts of Gotham.

## [Batcave II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRAwS.jpg)

In *Detective Comics #470*, Batcave II is revealed after Dick Grayson goes to college and Bruce moves away from the manor into the city. This was however only temporary and the Batcave returned below Wayne manor after returning to live there.

## [Prague Batcave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNAIG.jpg)

In *Batman and Robin Eternal #8*, a Batcave in some catacombs in Prague is revealed.

## [Lunar Batcave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3T2M.jpg)

In *Dark Days: The Forge*, Batman reveals that he has a Lunar Batcave, on the Moon. It even has [Robot Sentry Bats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9NG.jpg) to protect against unwelcome guests (although they do a pretty poor job against Superman).

## [Flying Batcave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlVy6.jpg)

The title of the 186th issue of *Detective Comics Volume 1* is "The Flying Batcave". Batman builds the Flying Batcave as to ensure Robin's safety he had to agree not to step foot in Gotham for a week.

## [Numerous Bat Bunkers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdxla.jpg)

In *Batwing #24*, Batwing's suit malfunctions after a fight with Lady Val, he asks Batman for the location of a R&D centre where he can fix his suit. Batman sends him the location for Bat Bunker 3, where he first gave Batwing the suit.

Comment: That is one heck of a list.. Thanks @Edlothiad.. However, I guess I should have been more specific. I'd read that there are 8 batcaves only in Gotham (regardless of the ones worldwide; or in this case, space-wide:p). Is that true?

Comment: Well given he calls the multitude of mini-caves he has "caves" I'm going to go with "depends on the writer and when they're writing"

Comment: Does he do anything else but preparing and maintaining his numerous bat caves? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Sourced from [ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/batcave/4020-31340/) will add the relevant comics when I find them.

There are actually 8 backup Batcaves and then the main one under Wayne Manor so these are the other 4.

#### The Batcave South-Central

> Is located in the Old Gotham prototype subway station, a four-block stretch of track sealed in 1896 and forgotten.

#### The Los Angeles Batcave

> Was used as a headquarters by the Outsiders when Batman rejoined the group. Another was introduced in 2002's Fugitive story arc, this time in the form of an abandoned submarine.

Mainly called [Batcave West](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batcave_West) and located in Los Angeles. It first appears in *Outsiders Volume 1 Issue 26* but was first mentioned at in *Issue 19*.

[image: Batcave West]

#### Arkham Cave

> Bruce created an Arkham Bat-cave when he found a secret location in Arkham Asylum called "Dead-Man's Point." This was where criminals came to commit suicide. Batman jumps off and bat-glides to this location from 100 feet up. An armored Bat-suit, batgrapple and bat bombs are examples of what is stored here.

#### Bat Bunker

> Under the penthouse of the Wayne Foundation building, there is a secret bunker. As of Batman #687, Dick Grayson has taken to using this as his Batcave, stating that he wishes to embody the role of Batman in a way that is specific to him as well as getting closer to the action in the city. The bunker is as well-equipped as the original Batcave, including the Subway Rocket vehicle stationed beneath the bunker.

[image: Bat Bunker]

Comment: Of course, he would need a trophy room.

Answer (score 2):

#### Londinium Batcave

In a three-part episode of the 1960's Batman series (Season 3, Episodes 11-13
November 23 - December 7, 1967), while Batman and the rest of the regular characters are visiting England for an international conference, Alfred sets up a temporary Batcave in the dungeon of a country house outside Londinium, even having the Batmobile and Batcomputer shipped across the Atlantic.

Batman uses this Batcave to solve the mysteries that he encounters across the pond, but there are glitches in the Batcomputer because of its journey, and it's only able to spit out brief answers like "wench", "winch", and "England swings like a pendulum do", so Batman and Alfred are left on their own to figure it all out.